# How can I use the "+" or "-" button to make the calcul and then the "=" to display it?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm trying to do a basic calculator. At first I only had two buttons "+" and "-", when i pressed one of the two buttons the text is displayed. For the next step, i want to display the result only when the "=" button is pressed. So basically "+" and "-" buttons are used to calculate and "=" to display the calcul. But nothing is displayed when "=" is pressed. Thanks for your help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JTextField tf1,tf2,tf3; JButton b1,b2, b3;

    Main() {
        tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf1.setBounds(50,50,150,20);
        tf2 = new JTextField();
        tf2.setBounds(50,100,150,20);
        tf3 = new JTextField();
        tf3.setBounds(50,150,150,20);
        tf3.setEditable(false);
        b1 = new JButton("+");
        b1.setBounds(50,200,50,50);
        b2 = new JButton("-");
        b2.setBounds(120,200,50,50);
        b3 = new JButton("=");
        b3.setBounds(190,200,50,50);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        add(tf1);add(tf2);add(tf3);add(b1);add(b2);add(b3);
        setSize(300,300);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
        int c = 0;
        Object buttonPressed = e.getSource();
        if (buttonPressed == b1 ){
            c= a+b;
            if(buttonPressed == b3){
                tf3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
            }
        }

        if(buttonPressed == b2){
            c=a-b;
            if(buttonPressed == b3){
                tf3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what should happen if user presses `+` or `-`? Should the code just *remember* what was pressed (do the calculation internally) but not display the result - if finally `=`  is pressed, the result should be updated?

Comment: __never-ever__ do manual sizing or locating, instead use a suitable layoutManager

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you nested your if statements. Look here:

```
if (buttonPressed == b1 ){
    c= a+b;
    if(buttonPressed == b3){
        tf3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
    }
}
```

This only executes when the variable buttonPressed is equal to b1.
But at the same time buttonPressed will never be b3, so that part never gets to execute.

You will need a sequence of if statements like so:

```
if (buttonPressed == b1) { ... }
if (buttonPressed == b2) { ... }
if (buttonPressed == b3) { ... }
```

You could also use different ActionListeners for each button.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class Calculat extends DocumentFilter implements DocumentListener {
    private int  result;
    private JButton  addButton;
    private JButton  equalsButton;
    private JButton  subtractButton;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JTextField  operand1textField;
    private JTextField  operand2textField;
    private JTextField  resultTextField;

    @Override // javax.swing.event.DocumentListener
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        handleDocumentEvent(event);
    }

    @Override // javax.swing.event.DocumentListener
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        handleDocumentEvent(event);
    }

    @Override // javax.swing.event.DocumentListener
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        // Never called.
    }

    @Override // javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
                        int offset,
                        int length,
                        String text,
                        AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        if (text != null  &&  !text.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(text);
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException xNumberFormat) {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            }
        }
        else {
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        }
    }

    private void buildAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text, String tooltip, ActionListener listener) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setToolTipText(tooltip);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(15.0f));
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 20));
        buttonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 20));
        addButton = createButton("\uFF0B", // Unicode addition symbol.
                                 "Add operands.",
                                 this::performAddition);
        buttonsPanel.add(addButton);
        subtractButton = createButton("\u2212", // Unicode subtraction symbol.
                                      "Subtract operands.",
                                      this::performSubtraction);
        buttonsPanel.add(subtractButton);
        equalsButton = createButton("=",
                                    "Display result.",
                                    this::produceResult);
        buttonsPanel.add(equalsButton);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 10));
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 30, 20, 30));
        operand1textField = createTextField();
        mainPanel.add(operand1textField);
        operand2textField = createTextField();
        mainPanel.add(operand2textField);
        resultTextField = createTextField();
        resultTextField.setEditable(false);
        mainPanel.add(resultTextField);
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private JTextField createTextField() {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(12);
        Document doc = textField.getDocument();
        doc.addDocumentListener(this);
        if (doc instanceof AbstractDocument) {
            AbstractDocument absDoc = (AbstractDocument) doc;
            absDoc.setDocumentFilter(this);
        }
        return textField;
    }

    private void handleDocumentEvent(DocumentEvent event) {
        boolean enable = operand1textField.getText().length() > 0  &&
                         operand2textField.getText().length() > 0;
        addButton.setEnabled(enable);
        subtractButton.setEnabled(enable);
        resultTextField.setText("");
    }

    private void performAddition(ActionEvent event) {
        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(operand1textField.getText());
        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(operand2textField.getText());
        result = op1 + op2;
        equalsButton.setEnabled(true);
        addButton.setEnabled(false);
        subtractButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void performSubtraction(ActionEvent event) {
        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(operand1textField.getText());
        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(operand2textField.getText());
        result = op1 - op2;
        equalsButton.setEnabled(true);
        addButton.setEnabled(false);
        subtractButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void produceResult(ActionEvent event) {
        resultTextField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
        equalsButton.setEnabled(false);
        addButton.setEnabled(false);
        subtractButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Calculat().buildAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

- The old *Swing* code examples usually use classes that extend `javax.swing.JFrame`. This is not required.
- `setLayout(null)` You rarely need to do this. Refer to [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) lesson in *Creating a GUI With Swing* trail of Oracle's Java tutorials.
- I think you should give meaningful names to your variables, for example `operand1textField` rather than `tf1`.
- I use a [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) to ensure that only digits are entered into the text fields for the operands.
- I use a [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) in order to know when the operands text fields are not empty and I only enable `addButton` and `subtractButton` once both operand text fields have values.
- I enable `equalsButton` only after the user has pressed either `addButton` or `subtractButton`.
- Since `java.awt.event.ActionListener` is a functional interface, I use [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), for example when `addButton` is pressed, method `performAddition` is called.

When launched, the GUI looks like this:

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `button` can't be both `b1` and `b3`.  You could introduce another variable that keeps track of the operator the user click on.  It could be a character, a string, or a button.  When the user click the "=" button, you then check the operator and perform the appropriate operation and display the result.

Another thing you have to think about is:  what does the program do when the user enter two numbers and click "=" button without providing an operator?

Here's my proposed solution based on your code.  Button `b1` and `b2` only update the variable `operator`.  Button `b3` performs the computation.

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JTextField tf1,tf2,tf3; JButton b1,b2, b3;
    char operator = '?';
    
    Main() {
        ...
        b1.addActionListener(e->operator='+');  
        b2.addActionListener(e->operator='-');  
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
        if (operator == '+') tf3.setText("" + (a+b));
        if (operator == '-') tf3.setText("" + (a-b));
        if (operator == '?') tf3.setText("Choose operator");
    }
}
```

Comment: using string concatenation to convert a number to string is *strange* - if you want to concatenate two or more values, then it is OK; but for conversion please use `Integer.toString` (example for `int`)  or `String.valueOf()` (as already done in question)